# Can we fly in Japan and/or Australia with EASA approved training and licences?

Tags: easa, pilot-certification

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a pilot, and seem to be lost with all the jargon and complexities around this matter despite trying to do adequate amount of research.

---

I am considering taking on my PPL in Hungary and it is all EASA approved training. Thereby the licence will be up to a standard of EASAs approval. Therefore with this licence, would I be able to fly in a foreign country such as Japan, Australia, etc. or other [countries with whom EASA has a working arrangement](https://www.easa.europa.eu/country-category/countries-whom-easa-has-working-arrangement)?

If not how would I be able to switch over my PPL to be accepted in Japan and Australia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need to hold a licence issued by the same country that the aircraft is registered in. There may be exceptions but you cannot fly an Australian aircraft on your EASA licence.

Luckily, converting a PPL between countries is generally straightforward when it has been issued by an ICAO-contracted state (which is most advanced countries and EASA).

For [Australia](https://www.casa.gov.au/standard-page/converting-overseas-licences), no additional tests are required (for PPL only, exams and flight tests are required for higher levels). You just need a medical, to pass a security check, and pay a fee. I believe EASA licences come with English Language Proficiency (ELP) level 4 to 6 so an English test is not required. Side note, the US does not have the ICAO ELP scheme so even native English speakers from there need to pass an English test when they convert to Australia.

I'm less familiar with Japan but according to [AOPA Japan](http://www.aopa.jp/Newenglish/Newenglish/Fly_1%20rev%202.html) you need to sit a law exam and obtain a radio operator certificate.

Comment: Surely the US has only native speakers of American.

Comment: @Ben would this also include NFVR &/or IR?  provided I just have a PPL?

Comment: @3kstc Neither NVFR nor IR come automatically with a PPL. If you have them issued by EASA then they can be converted, but they require a flight test. If EASA hasn't issued them to you, you need to complete the training for each rating from the beginning. I don't know if Japan is different on that.